# Delete last two elements from linked list in C

Tags: c, list, singly-linked-list

I have this piece of code, it deletes the last element from a linked list. What changes do I have to make so it will delete the last TWO elements of the linked list?

```
void deletesEnd() {
    struct node *temp, *last;

    temp = head;
    last = temp;

    while (temp != NULL && temp->next != NULL) {
        last = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    if (last == temp) {
        free(temp);
        head = NULL;
    } else {
        free(last->next);
        last->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't write a function for specifically deleting the last element. write a generic delete function and then, write this function in such a way that it will call the generic delete with the appropriate node. Also note, that `head = NULL` does nothing effectively because `head` is never used again. And be careful with your style, type the code as beautifully as you can.

Comment: I don't know what changes I have to do in order to work, I'd just like an explanation about the things I have to add so it will delete the last two, I'm not used with linked lists yet =/

Comment: Find a piece of paper, draw on it your list. Then try to remove a node by hand, you will suddenly understand why your function didn't work.

Comment: @iharob wouldn't it be wiser to keep the head = NULL?? If you don't do that, the head will contain a pointer to sth that has been `free`'d and you won't be ale to check later if you there is already a valid head or not. Or am I wrong? Please correct me if I am

Comment: Actually, what is the problem? Why not just call `deletesEnd` two times as it is (ofc. this requires `deletesEnd` to be correct for deleting one item)?

Comment: @iharob `head` is not a local variable inside `deletesEnd` scope, so you can't just assume something about its future usage from the question code.

Comment: @grek40 I did not notice that!!! That is a terrible, terrible thing. It is such a bad idea that I wouldn't expect `head` to be a global variable.

Comment: @Shofukan: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to remove the last 2 elements of the list is to call `deletesEnd()` twice.  Note that `deletesEnd()` should take `head` as an argument and return the new value. You would delete the last 2 by issuing a nested call:

```
struct node *deletesEnd(struct node *head) {
    struct node *temp, *last;

    last = temp = head;
    while (temp && temp->next != NULL) {
        last = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if (last == head) {
        free(head);
        head = NULL;
    } else {
        free(last->next);
        last->next = NULL;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Delete the last element: `head = deletesEnd(head);`

Delete the last 2 elements: `head = deletesEnd(deletesEnd(head));`

The simplicity of the design more than compensates for the overhead of enumerating the list twice.

If you absolutely want a specific function, you can extend your approach this way:

```
struct node *deleteLast2Nodes(struct node *head) {
    struct node *temp, *last;

    last = temp = head;
    while (temp && temp->next != NULL && temp->next->next != NULL) {
        last = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if (last == head) {
        if (head) {
            free(head->next);
        }
        free(head);
        head = NULL;
    } else {
        free(last->next->next);
        free(last->next);
        last->next = NULL;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how two last nodes can be deleted simultaneously.  In fact the function is similar to your function except it checks not only the `next` node but also the `next->next` node.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} *head;

void push( int value )
{
    struct node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    tmp->value = value;
    tmp->next  = head;

    head = tmp;
}

void display()
{
    for ( struct node *current = head; current; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", current->value );
    }
}

void deleteLastTwo()
{
    struct node *current = head;
    struct node *prev = head;

    if ( current && current->next )
    {
        while ( current->next->next )
        {
            prev = current;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    if ( current )
    {
        if ( current->next )
        {
            free( current->next );
        }

        if ( prev == current )
        {
            head = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            prev->next = NULL;
        }

        free( current );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 11;

    for ( int i = N; i != 0; i-- ) push( i - 1 );

    display();
    printf( "\n" );

    while ( head )
    {
        deleteLastTwo();
        display();
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
0 1 2 3 4 
0 1 2 
0
```

Take into account that it is not a good idea when the head node is declared like a global variable. It is better when it can be declared like a local variable. In this case you will need to rewrite the methods of the list because in most cases the current methods will not work correctly.

Comment: You can remove the test `if (current->next)` before `free(current->next);`. `free(NULL);` is perfectly defined.

Answer (score 0):

This  logic will delete your last 2 node in singly linked list.

```
void deletesEnd()
{
    struct node *temp, *last;

    temp = head;
    last = temp;

    while (temp->next->next != NULL)
    {
        last = temp->next;
        if(last->next->next!=NULL)
                temp = temp->next;
        else
                break;
    }

        struct node *ptr=last->next;
        last->next=ptr->next;
        free(ptr);

        temp->next=last->next;
        free(last);
}
```

Comment: This code will crash on an empty list, or one with a single element... actually it will crash on a list with 2 elements and probably many more cases.

Comment: @chqrlie I'm not going to check all condition here. I assumed user has a complete Linked list as he showed in his a question. He need to check rest condition. I just gave him logic only.

Answer (score 0):

For fun & education: simple recursive version.

- The function return := the number of nodes *below* `us`
- After the recursion returns, we can decide if we are too close to the tail.
- and remove ourselves
- because we pass a pointer to pointer, this should also work for lists of size=2 and smaller

---

```
unsigned del_tail_n(struct llist **pp, unsigned nn)
{
unsigned pos;
if (!*pp) return 0;

    // this recursive call returns 0 iff (*pp)->next is NULL
pos = del_tail_n( &(*pp)->next, nn);
if (pos < nn) {
        // free (*pp);
        *pp = NULL;
        }
return 1+pos;
}
```

---

For those who don't like recursion, here is a non-recursive version.
[do note that both versions work for empty lists `(*pp == NULL)` , or for lists smaller than `nn` ]

```
void del_tail_n2(struct llist **pp, unsigned nn)
{
struct llist *p;

        /* Advance p pointer n positions down, starting from *pp. */
for (p= *pp; p; p=p->next) {
        if (nn-- < 1) break;
        }

        /* Do a synchronous walk down for both p and *pp, until p is NULL. */
for ( ; p; p=p->next) {
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
        }

        /* Now, *pp is the first node to delete
        ** Delete it and everything below it.
        */
for ( ;(p = *pp); ){
        *pp = p->next;
        // free (p);
        }
return;
}
```

Comment: recursive iteration of lists without tail optimization would be one of the ways to get a stack overflow without allocating massive amounts of local data or failing the recursion anchor. It's perfectly fine to present a recursive solution, but the drawbacks should be mentioned.